# How to nest multiple pipes magrittr

Tags: r, magrittr

This starts as an aestethic question but then turns into a functional one, specifically about magrittr.

I want to add a *data_frame* which is manually input to one that is already there as so:

```
cars_0 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(brand = row.names(.)) %>%
  select(brand, mpg, cyl) 

new_cars <- matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T, c(
  "VW Beetle",   25, 4, 
  "Peugeot 406", 42, 6))   # Coercing types is not an issue here.

cars_1 <- rbind(cars_0, 
  set_colnames(new_cars, names(cars_0)))
```

I'm writing the new cars in a matrix for "increased legibility", and therefore need to set the column names for it to be bound to `cars_0`.

If anyone likes magrittr as much as I do, they might want to present `new_cars` first and pipe it to `set_colnames`

```
cars_1 <- rbind(cars_0, new_cars %>% 
  set_colnames(names(cars_0)))
```

Or to avoid repetition they'll want to indicate `cars_0` and pipe it to `rbind`

```
cars_1 <- cars_0 %>% 
  rbind(., set_colnames(new_cars, names(.)))
```

However one cannot do both as there is confusion about whom is being piped

```
cars_1 <- cars_0 %>% 
  rbind(., new_cars %>% set_colnames(names(.)))
## Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
##   names do not match previous names
```

My question:  Is there a way to distinguish the two arguments that are piped?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: I'm not sure what the rationale for doing this would be. The philosophy behind `magrittr` was to *unnest* composite functions, with the primary intent of making it easier to read the code.  For example:

```
f(g(h(x)))
```

becomes

```
h(x) %>% g() %>% f()
```

Trying to use pipes in a manner that places two objects to be interpreted as the `.` argument goes against the philosophy of simplification.  There are circumstances in which you can have nested pipes, but the environments ought to remain distinct.  Trying to cross two pipes in the same environment can be likened to crossing the streams.

[image]

Don't cross the streams :)

Comment: Fair enough.  Cheers.