# Nested function is a missing argument - magrittr error

Tags: r, magrittr

This may go against the philosophy of magrittr ([ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577565/how-to-nest-multiple-pipes-magrittr), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577565/how-to-nest-multiple-pipes-magrittr))

Still, magrittr throws an error in the simplest of nested functions.

```
x <- c(3, 1,2, 3) %>%
  sort(unique())
## Error in is.factor(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

```
x <- c(3, 1,2, 3) %>%
  sort(unique(.))
## Error in sort(., unique(.)) : 
##   'decreasing' must be a length-1 logical vector.
## Did you intend to set 'partial'?
```

Can any explain this behaviour or how to avoid it?

Comment: Why not `c(3, 1, 2, 3) %>% unique() %>% sort()`?

Comment: I know this is possible but I wanted to know if there was a way to use nested functions even so

Answer (score 1):

I think I can provide a partial answer (concerning how to *avoid* this behavior).

Just enclose the nested function call in braces like so:

```
c(3, 1, 2, 3) %>% {sort(unique(.), decreasing = FALSE)}
# [1] 1 2 3
```

As to why this works, that's explained in ?magrittr::`%>%\`.